# Require multiple submodules from single JS file with Node/Component.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a single JS file (in a private github repo with myDependency as an example).

I have moved several submodules into this repo and want to require these individually in my app.

So far I have the following (all example names):

"myDependency":

index.js/

```
module.exports = function () {
require(".first");
require(".second");
require(".third");
require(".fourth");
require(".fifth");
require(".sixth");
require(".seventh");
require(".eighth");
require(".ninth");
};
```

In my component.json I would like to do the following:

```
dependencies: {
    "privateRepoName/myDependency": "master"
}
```

Then in my script:

```
var first = myDependency.first;
```

This is not working.  I do not have access to the methods in first.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What did `console.log(myDependency)` show?

Comment: You are retuning a function and requiring modules in the local scope. Export an object `{ first: require('module') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `require` functions is not exposed in the index.js. As it is , `myDependency` is a function object, which doesn't return anything when called.

To fix this, export an object, with all the required modules, like this

```
module.exports = {
    "first"  : require("./first"),
    "second" : require("./second"),
    "third"  : require("./third"),
    "fourth" : require("./fourth"),
    ...
}
```

Please note that the paths should start with `./`, not just `.`.